# Is the binarization of a multi-class classification worse than a binary classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, mathematical-statistics, dimensionality-reduction

**BACKGROUND**

Consider $N$ classes $\{C_1, \cdots, C_N\}$ such that the contingency matrix $\mathcal{M}^{\scriptsize(N)}$ produced by some mutli-class classifier $M^{\scriptsize(N)}$ on a test set is $N$-by-$N$. Now assume that classes $\{C_1, \cdots, C_k\}$ and $\{C_{k+1}, \cdots, C_N\}$ can be bundled into two coarse-grained classes $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $\mathcal{C}_2$, respectively. We then train a binary classifier $M^{\scriptsize(\mbox{bin.})}$ such that its output contingency matrix $\mathcal{M}^{\scriptsize(\mbox{bin.})}$ is 2-by-2.

For the sake of simplicity, assume that the number of training examples is more than enough so that all classes are amply (and equally) represented in the training set. Also assume that both models $M^{\scriptsize(N)}$ and $M^{\scriptsize(\mbox{bin.})}$ are optimally trained and tuned.

**QUESTION**

Will the collapsing of $\mathcal{M}^{\scriptsize(N)}$ into a 2-by-2 matrix converge to the exact same matrix as $\mathcal{M}^{\scriptsize(\mbox{bin.})}$, i.e. notwithstanding statistical or implementational artefacts? Can this be proved either way?